# Weird reflections from HDRi

Tags: materials, windows, hdri

I have been having some problem with reflections in my windows and can't find out what I am doing wrong. I have purchased 2 car models and I get the same problem with the windows. Is is the model itself that are making it or my HDR or perhaps the material?

I am posting a screenshot of the scene, I have also added a sphere just to you can see that in the sphere I think it looks correct.

[image]

Posting the final result here, but made it in photoshop.

[image]

Latest dumps from blender with magnifying effect and normals.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a normals issue with the glass

Comment: Thanks got info. I am quite a beginner so can you please explain more in detail what the problem in with the normals?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The material isn’t glass in the principled shader - you have Metallic set to 1.0 and Transmission set to 0.0. It’s essentially a reflective metallic surface. If you don’t specifically need to use the Principalled shader then just delete that node and replace it with a Glass Shader node - much simpler to use. Alternatively, start by changing Metallic to zero and Transmission very close to 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it but no luck. Its also making the background like you see in a magnifying glass. Maybe that the reality but I don't like it.
Still some weird reflections. This time I made the windows in photoshop but it any one else have any suggestion regarding this please make a comment.
Posting the final windows/glass I am happy with.

Comment: @gubbfet If it’s magnifying then there’s definitely something going on with your normals - with a pane of glass the normals should all be pointing out in the same direction - possibly you have the window mesh set to Smooth rather than Flat?

Comment: So I have posted screenshots of the normals it looks like they are pointing outwards. And I tried to put the object to flat but the reflection is now then looking like minekraft :) if you know what I mean.

Comment: @gubbfet The side windows look ok to me but the *front* one looks wrong - looks like it’s just a single plane rather than a manifold mesh - has it got thickness? Try addinng a solidify modifier.

Answer (score 2):

Set your *Principled Shader* *Transmission* to 1.0 (not *Metalic*) and make sure your windows are shaded flat, that solved the problem for me!

Don't forget to add a *Solidify Modifier* too.

Comment: What does it mean to have your windows shaded flat? Where you do you set that please? (I am having spherical reflections on my flat window.)

Comment: I think I have found it, thanks to @Rich Sedman